Time series classification, using lagged data, and exogenous time series variables for exploratory features
I have the following pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({
    'region': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
    'week': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
    'rain': [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    'clouds': [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
})

region  week    rain    clouds
0   1   1   1   1
1   1   2   1   1
2   1   3   0   0
3   1   4   1   0
4   2   1   1   0
5   2   2   1   0
6   2   3   1   1
7   2   4   1   0
8   3   1   1   1
9   3   2   0   0
10  3   3   0   0
11  3   4   0   0

which indicates at a specific region, at a specific week, if it rained, considering if there clouds at that region at that week.
In my toy example, I would like to be able to predict if it will rain at week n, taking into account if it rained the previous weeks and also if there were clouds the previous weeks.
How could I achieve that ? What would be an appropriate model for this type of problems ?

The data that you want to predict is living on $\{0,1\}$, so I would suggest a binary time, for instance generalized binary AR. Another way to go about it is to use a generalized linear model with the bernoulli distribution. I think when you google/research these phrases you fill find something useful.
